# Is there a way to specify file name using wildcards in selinux type_transition rules?

Tags: linux, selinux

This kind of rules works perfect if filename matches exactly one specified at the end of rule, but not with wildcards.
The star in the example below does not work. Well, actually it does, but it is treated as a part of filename, not as a "regex"

```
module test 1.2;


require {
    type unconfined_t;
    type httpd_sys_rw_content_t;
    type usr_t;
    class file {create};
}

type_transition unconfined_t usr_t:file httpd_sys_rw_content_t "test*";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible, as *name transitions* do not support wildcards/regular experissions. [Red Hat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sec-file-name-transition) has a note regarding this:

> Note that file name transition uses an exact match done by the `strcmp()` function. Use of regular expressions or wildcard characters is not considered.

Comment: I removed my answer, as this one is more directly related to exactly what the OP was asking.